# Bracha on Natural Wonders

Tags: halacha, blessing, natural-phenomenon

Is the bracha שככה לו בעולמו still said on natural wonders? It is in my siddur but I have never heard it said, rather, people often opt to say עושה מעשה בראשית. Which bracha would be said on a natural wonder such as the Grand Canyon or the Himelayas?

Comment: Related (and see other questions linked there): http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16854/is-there-an-exhaustive-list-of-astronomical-environmental-events-for-which-there

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/14274/759

Answer (score 1):

שככה לו בעולמו is actually said on beautiful animals or people.

If you're thinking of שכוחו וגבורתו מלא עולם, then the custom is to say it only on thunder, and to say עושה מעשה בראשית on most other natural phenomena and wonders. See [here](http://www.torah.org/learning/halacha/classes/class219.html) and [here](http://www.torah.org/learning/halacha/classes/class220.html).

Comment: Is it still said or not?

Comment: I thought that משנה הבריות is said on beatufiul animals or people?

Comment: That's for "unusual looking" animals or people