# Does one make a blessing on wondrous man-made structures?

Tags: halacha, blessing, natural-phenomenon

Halacha codifies making a blessing on wondrous natural events and places ([see here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16856/7034)). I would like to know if any halachic authorities discuss making a blessing on wondrous man-made structures such as the Great Wall of China or the Large Hadron Collider

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37925/bracha-on-natural-wonders

Comment: Who would you be praising in the blessing? The designer? God?

Comment: @DoubleAA I would only be praising God! I would assume phraseology such as 'SheNatan MeChachmato LeBasar VeDam' - the blessing made on seeing an outstanding non-Jewish scholar (S”A 224:7), would be appropriate. Perhaps also ברוך אתה ה' אלהינו מלך העולם שככה לו בעולמו (ibid 225:10) as said on beautiful creations and good trees

Comment: @DoubleAA Most likely thanking G-d for the designer, I would assume.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I am aware of and the Artscroll siddur also doesn't mention it.

R Shlomo Aviner [was asked](http://www.ravaviner.com/2017/12/short-sweet-text-message-q-341_19.html) whether one should make a *shechechiyanu* blessing regarding the new tunnel on the Yerushalayim-Tel Aviv road (of course it pales in comparison with the Great Wall or LHC!)

> Q: There is a new tunnel on the Yerushalayim-Tel Aviv Road  which
>   greatly eases the traffic.  Is it permissible for me to recite
>   Shechechiyanu when I drive through it for the first time?
>
> A: It does not seem so, since this is not included among the general
>   rules for reciting this blessing.  See Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim
>   222-223.  Perhaps one may recite it if he is happy, since it is "good news" (ibid. [222:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.222.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)), but it does not seem so.

If there was an appropriate blessing for a man-made creation R Aviner would surely have mentioned it.

Comment: I upvoted your answer. But it only deals with "Shechechiyanu"; it does not deal with other possibilities eg the blessing made on seeing an outstanding non-Jewish scholar as the OP said in a comment.

Comment: I know and agree - but I think if there was another appropriate blessing for a man-made creation R Aviner would surely have mentioned it. That is the point, combined with the absence of mention in the Artscroll siddur. But your point is well taken

Comment: Note: Just because the ArtScroll Siddur doesn't mention it doesn't mean the _bracha_ doesn't exist.

Comment: @ezra Of course but, as you know, proving the absence of something is really hard. So I bring three hints it might not exist: (1) Artscroll doesn't mention it ... (2) R Aviner doesn't either ... (3) mbloch doesn't know it (:->)