# Should I say the Bracha ברוך...שככה לו בעולמו when I marvel at fall foliage?

Tags: halacha, blessing, trees

Follow up on [Bracha on beautiful people](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43926/bracha-on-beautiful-people):

The beauty of fall foliage is sometimes stunning. The beauty of foliage is "general" meaning that I see a hill with a group of trees and the whole group together is beautiful.

Can I make the bracha ברוך...שככה לו בעולמו on this entire group? Can I make this bracha on a single tree that I randomly choose even though looking at a single tree doesn't leave me with the "beautiful" impression as the group does? What if I see this view from a distance and can't specify 1 tree?

Comment: The Rambam Berachos (10:13), Rosh Berachos (9:12), Rif Berachos (43b) and Tur (225) poskin the Gemara Berachos (58a) saying to make a beracha on seeing beautiful trees - ראה בריות טובות או בהמה ואילנות טובות אומר ברוך אתה ה' אלהינו מלך העולם שככה לו בעולמו.

Answer (score -5):

I don't think so, reductum ad absurdum, if I would see a beautiful fallen oak leaf sprinkled with dew sparkling in the sunlight could I make a beracha on a leaf?

Comment: Why can't you make the beracha on a leaf? What a terrible _absurdum_.

Comment: What's so absurd about enjoying the beautiful things and events in nature and making a bracha on them? There is a bracha made on observing beautiful people and animals. I find lightning bolts and meteors beautiful, and a I make a bracha when I see them. Choni Hama'gal made a "bracha" on a beautiful tree. Do you makea bracha on lettuce? If you do, you're making  a bracha on a leaf!